# Is multiprocessing the right tool for me?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to write a very specific data processing daemon.

Here is how I thought it could work with multiprocessing :

- Process #1: One process to fetch some vital meta data, they can be fetched every second, but those data must be available in process #2. Process #1 writes the data, and Process #2 reads them.
- Process #2: Two processes which will fetch the real data based on what has been received in process #1. Fetched data will be stored into a (big) queue to be processed "later"
- Process #3: Two (or more) processes which poll the queue created in Process #2 and process those data. Once done, a new queue is filled up to be used in Process #4
- Process #4 : Two processes which will read the queue filled by Process(es) #3 and send the result back over HTTP.

The idea behind all these different processes is to specialize them as much as possible and to make them as independent as possible.

All thoses processes will be wrapped into a main daemon which is implemented here :

- http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/

I am wondering if what I have imagined is relevant/stupid/overkill/etc, especially if I run daemon `multiprocessing.Process`(es) within a main parent process which will daemonized.
Furthermore I am a bit concerned about potential locking problems. In theory processes that read and write data uses different variables/structures so that should avoid a few problems, but I am still concerned.

Maybe using multiprocessing for my context is not the right thing to do. I would love to get your feedback about this.

Notes :

- I can not use Redis as a data structure server
- I thought about using ZeroMQ for IPC but I would avoid using another extra library if multiprocessing can do the job as well.

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your division in different workers with different tasks as well as your plan to let them communicate already looks good. However, one thing you should be aware of is whenever a processing step is I/O or CPU bound. If you are I/O bound, I'd go for the threading module whenever you can: the memory footprint of your application will be smaller and the communication between threads can be more efficient, as shared memory is allowed. Only if you need additional CPU power, go for multiprocessing. In your system, you can use both (it looks like process 3 (or more) will do some heavy computing, while the other workers will predominantly be I/O bound).